# How to change from integer (empty) to 0 in r

Tags: r, dataframe, is-empty

How can I create a condition so that if a variable returns the value (empty) in r, it will convert to an actual 0, so I can include it in a larger data frame that will display the value '0' for that variable?

I do not know which variables will return empty, so I want to include this as a condition on all variables before I run the code.

Here is what I have:

`` groups_ba = df$unique_groups[groupdata_unique$`Appointment Type`=="BA GROUP"] ``

If the data contains the appointment type 'BA GROUP', I want the value of groups_ba to correspond to the number of BA GROUP, which it currently does. However, if the data does not contain the appointment type 'BA GROUP', I want the value of groups_ba to be 0, rather than what it currently gives me, which is 'empty'.

Comment: `if(length(blah) == 0) 0`? Hard to tell without a little context of how/where this will be used.

Comment: I added a bit more to the question, let me know if I need to add even more. Thanks!

Comment: Please share a few rows of sample data--say one group that does have a "BA GROUP" value and one that doesn't, along with the desired result for that sample input just to make sure it is very clear. The nicest way to share sample data is in copy/pasteable R syntax, which you can produce with `dput()`, e.g., `dput(df[1:5, c(2, 4)])` for the first 5 rows of columns 2 and 4. Choose a suitable subset to illustrate the problem.